# Getting objects from to-many relationship in Swift Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many

I have been having some difficulties revolving around using to-many relationships in Core Data with Swift.

My data model

[image]

What I am trying to do is to use an instance of a `Country` and then display all of the `Contacts` that are citizens of that country. As I have been trying to do this, I have constructed a UITableViewController that will display all of the citizens of the country. However I have had major problems of getting the actual `Contacts` out of the relationship `citizensOfCountry`. Here is the code that I am using (only relevant parts).

```
class ShowingCitizensOfCountry: UITableViewController {

     var countryToShow: Country?
     //This is a value that is passed by a prepareForSegue method
     override func viewDidLoad() {
          //how do I get a list/set/other iterable object of Contacts?

          //***Line in question***
          let listOfPeople = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry

          for citizen in listOfPeople {
              println(citizen)//THIS IS NOT WORKING
          }

     }
```

So, this is not working at all. Right now in the for loop I get a compiler error that says `Type 'Contacts' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence Type'`. What I don't understand about this is that it is just of type Contact... I would think that it would be some sort of collection. So, that wasn't working so I tried this.

```
let listOfPeople = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry as! [Contacts]
```

This doesn't work either and I get the error `'NSArray' is not a subtype of 'Contacts'`. Next I tried converting with a NSSet.

```
let listOfPeople = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry as! NSSet<Contacts>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either and I get the warnings `Cast from 'Contacts' to unrelated type 'NSSet' always fails` and `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSSet'`. Next I tried something else. I tried using the `valueForKey` method.

```
let listOfPeople = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry.valueForKey("name") as! Set<String>
```

This works! I could print out just the name of all the people that are a citizen of that country. However I don't understand why. Why does it work when I use `valueForKey("name")` but I can't get an individual Contact? Is there a better way to be doing this that I have simply missed? Any explanation about why I am not able to get a collection of `Contacts` from a single `Country` is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry because I'm really tired I couldn't read everything. But from what I've read, you want to get the citizens of a country which should be a `NSSet`. To get that you can simply do: `yourArrayOfCountries.flatMap { $0. citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts] }`. I'll post it as an answer, to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry because I'm really tired I couldn't read everything. But from what I've read, you want to get the citizens of a country which should be a NSSet. To get that you can simply do:

```
let contacts = yourArrayOfCountries.flatMap { 
    $0.citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts] 
}
```

According to your comment:

```
let contacts = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts]
```

Comment: It might be that I am doing something idiotic, but I wrote `let listOfPeople = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry.flatMap { $0.citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts] }` and I got the error `'Contacts' does not have a member named 'flatMap'` Was this what you meant?

Comment: You can only use `flatMap` on an array. What you did is on the `NSSet` so it doesn't work. Try `countryToShow!.flatMap { $0.citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts] }`. I'm assuming `countryToShow` is the array of `Country`.

Comment: yeah, that doesn't work either. `countryToShow` is a Country object and I am trying to follow the relationship to find the citizens of the country. In case you care, the error that I get by using your code is `'Country' does not have a member named 'flatMap'`

Comment: Ah sorry, I was assuming countryToShow was an Array. Ill update the answer.

Comment: `let contacts = countryToShow!.citizensOfCountry.allObjects as! [Contacts]` should work. Let me know :)

Comment: That doesn't work either, I get `'Contacts' does not have a number named 'allObjects'`. Thanks though.

Comment: Strange. If you check `citizensOfCountry`, what type does it say it is? Normally it should be `NSSet` and using the code I've provided should do the trick.

Comment: it says that it is of type `Contacts`, which is weird.

Comment: Indeed it is, if it's `Contacts` then it seems like it's a one to one relationship instead of one to many. In the class declaration of Country, is `citizensOfCountry` set as `NSSet` or `Contacts`?

Comment: There's the problem. It all works well now. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: cool, worked like a charm in Swift 3, the converting NSSet to Array part for a core Data one To Many scenario.  "NSSetObject.allObjects as! [myArray]" . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your errors is that the to-many relationship results in a `NSSet`. All of your attempts to iterate though these sets should take this into account.

Much better is to implement a `NSFetchResultsController`, the standard way for displaying Core Data in a table view.

- In the FRC, fetch people
- Have the FRC sort by whatever you need
- Give it a predicate that filters for the `countryToShow`

FRC implementation:

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"countryOfOrigin = %@", self.countryToShow!)
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
       fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, 
       sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
        NSLog("%@", error!)
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil
```

*I made Contacts into the more appropriate singular.*

Comment: So in this solution would I even be using the `citizensOfCountry` relationship? Or would I just be filtering all of the Contacts based on their `countryOfOrigin` relationship?

Comment: It is the same because they are reverse relationships. Because you are using the `Contacts` entity, you would use `countryOfOrigin`. I will amend my answer to show you how it is done.

Comment: Just for my own curiosity, ifI had already found the `Country` wouldn't it then be more efficient to then use the `citizensOfCountry` relationship to find the `Contacts`, or would It be the same?

Comment: In principle, yes. But then you could not use the fetched results controller for your table view with all the added benefits.